# Delete if no row matches condition in a table - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a SQL table with the following rows:

1. Name: Null, Id: 15
2. Name: 'MyName', Id: 15

I want to delete all the rows with Name = NULL but ONLY IF rows with column Name IS NOT NULL don't exist in the table. So in this case it shouldn't delete any row. However, if it finds:

1. Name: Null, Id: 15
2. Name: 'Null', Id: 15

it should delete both rows.

I have tried this query but it doesn't work:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE Name = NULL 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM MyTable a 
LEFT JOIN ...
LEFT JOIN ... 
WHERE Name IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: `WHERE Name = NULL` can *never* be true; nothing equals `NULL`, including `NULL`. When comparing against `NULL` values, you *must* use `IS NULL` (which you oddly *do* use in your subquery).

Comment: @Larnu Thanks. The query still doesn't work the way it should though, even if I replace the equal sign with IS.

Comment: Consumable sample data would help us help you, ideally as DDL and DML statements. Your description of your data is a little harder to consume; especially when you have both "Null" and "'Null'"; are you storing both the value `NULL` and the `varchar` value `'Null'`..? Are you expecting those values to be treated equally? They are *not* and should not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `EXISTS`

```sql
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE Name IS NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM MyTable t2
    WHERE t2.Name IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try like This

```
   DELETE FROM 
    MyTable
    WHERE  
    
    Name like '%NULL%' OR  
    Name like '%Null%'  OR  
    Name like '%null%'
```