# Delete rows based on group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have the following table:

```
Id | QuestionId
----------------
 1 | 'MyQuestionId'
 1 | NULL
 2 | NULL
 2 | NULL
```

It should behave like so

- Find all the results of the same Id
- If ANY of them has QuestionId IS NOT NULL, do not touch any rows with that Id.
- Only if ALL the results for the same Id have QuestionId IS NULL, delete *all the rows* with that Id.

So in this case it should only delete rows with Id=2.

I haven't found an example for such a case anywhere. I've tried some options with rank, count, group by, but nothing worked. Can you help me?

Comment: Seems to be the same issue as [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72732061/delete-if-no-row-matches-condition-in-a-table-sql-server) which you marked as answered. Is it (with slight variation of using ID to correlate)?

Comment: @SMor if there is a variation maybe it's not a duplicate after all?

Comment: @forpas This is explicitly *not* the same as the previous question, which I also answered. That one wants to know if *any* rows in the whole table are not null, this is a question of partitioning/grouping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an updatable CTE or derived table for this, and calculate the count using a window function.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*,
      CountNonNulls = COUNT(t.QuestionId) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Id)
    FROM YourTable t
)
DELETE cte
WHERE CountNonNulls = 0;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02a8c45d5055bee9ac1353bedd02bdaf)

Note that this query does not contain any self-joins at all.

Comment: You haven't shown how that join would be needed so couldn't say. Probably inside the CTE although in some cases it could be outside. A self-join is not necessary in this case, as I noted. You would only need joins if you want data from other tables

Comment: I wanted to add a left join after FROM, but it won't let me because I am joining on Id, which it says was already specified for cte.

Comment: That's because you are doing `SELECT *` so it selects all columns from all tables. Instead do `SELECT t.*`

Comment: Ok I can join now, but I can't delete anymore because 'View or function 'cte' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.'

Comment: Hmm, might need to use a `WHERE EXISTS` semi-join. I suggest you create a new question showing what tables and joins you have